# Removing letter code gone wrong (C++)

Tags: c++, string, char

I was writing this code below that is suppose to take in information from the user ( a sentence ) and remove the desired letter. However, it only works if that sentence is one word. If the information contains a space, it will terminate at the space.Any advice as how I can get the program to read the entire sentence?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>


using namespace std;

int main() {
string sentence;
char letterRemoved;

//Entering in Information
cout <<"Enter a sentence here!";
cin >> sentence;

cout <<"Enter letter to remove";
cin>>letterRemoved;

//Removing Occurence of letter
sentence.erase(remove(sentence.begin(), sentence.end(),letterRemoved), sentence.end());

//Print out
cout<<sentence << "\n";

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Reading input using `cin >> sentence` only reads until whitespace is encountered, and then stops. If you want to read an entire line (until the user presses enter), you want to use [`std::getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/):

```
getline(cin, sentence);
```

Alternately, if you want to read up until a full stop character or a newline is found, you can use the `delimeter` argument to `getline`:

```
getline(cin, sentence, '.');
```